# DateWise Query with sum count in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Below is the one is my actual resulset in oracle database

```
TIMESTAMP          SUCESS  FAILURE  

26-01-2017            1      0    

31-01-2017            0      1
```

If i select from `26-01-2017` to `31-01-2017` .Query has to return like this below

expected resultset

Timestamp 26-01-2017  27-01-2017 28-01-2017  29-01-2017   30-01-2017 31-01-2017

Sucess      1             0          0         0             0         0      |

Failure     0             0          0         0             0         0

```
 Please can anyone give me suggestions to write logic for above expected resultset?
```

Comment: What is a **sum count**? Also: why do you want to show the output with columns for each date? Your current format (with one row for each date) is the correct format. To get columns based on the data is generally a bad idea; it can't be done directly, it requires dynamic SQL which is generally best not to use. If you really need the data in that format, do it in your reporting application. But really find out why this format is in the requirement, since it's a bad idea. (Then: you can't have `-` in column names, and names can't begin with digits, unless you double-quote the names - bad idea!)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a PIVOT (I made an assumption that you always have either success or failure):

```
select * from (
select decode(success, 1, 'success', 'failure') as res_name, 
       success+failure as res, 
       to_char(time_stamp, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ts 
from your_table)
pivot (max(res) for ts in ('26-01-2017', '27-01-2017', '28-01-2017', '29-01-2017', '30-01-2017', '31-012017'))
```

List of columns is always defined up front, so if you need a variable list of columns you need either generate above query or use PIVOT XML. With PIVOT XML you can use subquery instead of predefined list of variables, but you get XML back.